# How to create List<Integer> in xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a problem with xml transforming. I am using Saxon, xslt 2.0, and in my object I have a list of integers:

```
<Object>
    <accounts>
        <xsl:value-of select="CAOptDtls/BOwnrId/PrtryId" />
    <accounts>
<Object>
```

Previously it was single integer and it was working fine, now I wanted to use list of integers and now I was trying to make it a list in transformer but I failed.

If I tried:

```
<accounts>
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="CAOptDtls/BOwnrId/PrtryId" />
    </item>
</accounts>
```

Exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: item : item
---- Debugging information ----
message             : item
cause-exception     : 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : item
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /Object/accounts/item
line number         : 111
class[1]            : pl.test.Object
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : not available
```

If I tried only xsl:value-of with  my JUnit test says that he wanted something like that:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...
    <accounts[ class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
        <a class="java.lang.Integer-array">
            <int>320</int>
        </a]>
    </accounts> but was:<...
    <accounts[>
       <int>320</int]>
    </accounts>
```

Googled it for long time and still don't get the answer.

// EDIT

Okay, so, this is a part of my xsl -

```
<Object>
...
    <accounts>
        <xsl:value-of select="CAOptDtls/BOwnrId/PrtryId" />
    </accounts>
...
</Object>
```

My Object in Java have a collection:

```
List<Integer> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the xml to transform:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <CAOptDtls>
        <BOwnrId>
            <PrtryId>320</PrtryId>
        </BOwnrId>
    </CAOptDtls>
    ...
</Document>
```

And now with the try to transform as above the error is:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...
    <accounts[ class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
        <a class="java.lang.Integer-array">
            <int>320</int>
        </a>
    </accounts]>
</Object>> but was:<...
    <accounts[/]>
</Object>>
```

Comment: `xsl:value-of` inserts a *text node* into the result tree, so the behavior revealed by the JUnit output is a bit weird.  If the XSL you present is responsible for that, then it must be the case that `CAOptDtls/BOwnrId/PrtryId` resolves to an element whose text content is (escaped) XML, and that you have disabled output escaping.  If you want a good answer then I think you would be best off presenting a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I make a little mistake there cause I was trying different options and forgot to delete node <int>, I will edit my post above.

Comment: Finally - it wasn't the error of the xsl or sth else - in my test I was initializing my list as Arrays.asList(xxx) - not new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(xxx)). After I fixed it I must create elements in <int> nodes but its working